# Component returning null when called in flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I have a flow that calls a component I created and passes it a recordId for a contact. The flow then takes that recordId and through the controller action calls a custom apex controller. I'm expecting the component to set a variable called shouldProgress as either true or false based on what the apex controller returns but for some reason it only returns null. I don't have a ton of experience creating this sort of lightning component so I'm sure there's something I'm missing.

This is the apex controller class:

```
public with sharing class fullCircleOppGatingController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static boolean shouldCreateOpp(String contactId) {
        if(!FCRM.FCR_SupportAPI.IsPassiveMode()) {
                List<CampaignMember> activeResponses = FCRM.FCR_SupportAPI.GetActiveResponses(new List<Id> { contactId });
                if(activeResponses.size() == 0) {
                    return false;
                } 
        }
    
        return true;
    }
}
```

I can pass a contactId to the controller in anonymous apex and get the expected result so I know this portion is working.

This is the lightning component:

```
<aura:component controller="fullCircleOppGatingController" implements="lightning:availableForFlowActions,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="shouldProgress" type="Boolean" access="global" />
</aura:component>
```

This is the controller for the component:

```
({
    invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
        var contactID = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.shouldCreateOpp");
        action.setParams({ contactId : contactID });
        action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
            component.set("v.shouldProgress", data.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

When I run this in the flow debug I get the following:

> **C:CALLFULLCIRCLEOPPORTUNITYGATING (LOCAL ACTIONS): Full Circle Opportunity Gate**
> **Inputs:**
> recordId = {!Get_Contact.Id} (003DD00001RMptoYAD)
> shouldProgress = {!shouldProgress} (null)
> **Outputs:**
> recordId (003DD00001RMptoYAD)
> shouldProgress (null)

From the flow I'm only passing the recordId and I'm not passing the variable shouldProgress. When I get the response from the component shouldProgress is null where I would expect it to be true or false based on if the contact has an active response status.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks for reading!!

Comment: Hi @dkeefer, have you debugged that the contactId is being passed to your Apex controller? I suspect what is happening is that there is an error being thrown on the server side, so you aren't actually getting a successful response but an error instead. Best practice is to check the state of the response (either error or success) as shown in this example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

Comment: Hi @CallumMacErlich, thanks for the response! Sorry, I should have mentioned that I did put some debug statements in the apex controller and have verified that it is returning the expected true/false based on the contact. I definitely need to add the state check going forward though. Any other thoughts as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: No worries at all. Have you also debugged the JavaScript in your aura component (specifically that the getReturnValue() function does return a value)? Also are you expecting this to occur on the same screen, or is this passed to the flow for subsequent screens/nodes to use?